# Why Bufferstrategy flushes / won't show() when outside of rendering loop?

Tags: java, awt, bufferstrategy

The following code will flush/clear the current buffer of the canvas ( a black screen will be displayed for a split second maybe and after that nothing will be displayed - which is not what I expected because I haven't stated for the buffer to be flushed )

```
public class Main {
    static int width = 200;
    static int height = 200 ;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        BufferStrategy bs;
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(width,height);

        canvas.setPreferredSize(dim);
        jframe.setResizable(false);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.add(canvas);
        jframe.pack();
        jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        canvas.requestFocus();

        bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
            bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0,0,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight());
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
}
```

However, if the line of code `bs.show()` is changed into the following:

```
while(true){
    bs.show();
}
```

Then the screen will be filled with black color as wanted.

Or even if we write ( I didn't add try-catch around `Thread.sleep()` for simplicity):

```
while(true){
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    bs.show();
}
```

Then the window is filled with black as wanted.

My questions:

1. In the first code, why the window is flushed and the black filling of the window is not seen? does `show()` clear the current buffer? ( even though I haven't told it so) and if so, then what is the time it takes for the buffer to be cleared?
   if `show()` indeed clears the buffer after some time then why in the third piece of code the black filling is seen no matter how much time our thread sleeps?
2. How do I make Bufferstrategy in the first code to continue and `show()` the black filled rectangle without putting it in a loop?

Thanks!

Comment: There's lots of reasons why a `BufferStrategy` may not render.  Just because you've called `setVisible` on the window doesn't mean that by the time you try and present the `BufferStrategy`, the window is in a state which would allow it to be painted.  `BufferStrategy` is also considered to be volatile, this means that between requesting a page (ie `getDrawGraphics`) and calling `show`, the page may have become invalid and can no longer be drawn to the screen.  The short answer is to you question is, you can't, but you don't need a loop which runs for ever.

Comment: See the [`BufferStrategy` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) for a runnable example of how you should be using it.  The next question though is, why?  The main reasons for using `BufferStrategy` is to control the rendering workflow and get "as close to the metal" rendering, which is usually used for high demand graphics and animation - which would suggest a requirement for a "render loop"

Comment: I've read it before posting but one thing was bothering me - there could be a scenario as such: between two successive calls to strategy.show() in the loop, long enough time might've elapsed so that the drawing buffer was lost and so the screen might flicker between frames, how could such a situation be resolved?

Comment: I doubt, very highly, you'd get "flickering" using `BufferStrategy` as it's, well double buffered, so the "last" frame will remain until you switch to the new frame - this is, also, another reason for using it - although, Swing, if used properly, is also double buffered by default

Comment: Even so, there is no guarantee the last frame will remain on the current buffer ( or any frame will remain on the other buffers in case of two or more buffering ) by the time I reach 'show()' again ( or 'contentsRestored()' ) to switch to the new frame; so I could still get a flicker, theoretically.

Comment: *"Even so, there is no guarantee the last frame will remain on the current buffer"* - why do you say that?  Until you "switch" pages, the last frame will remain on the "surface" - think of it like a slide show, until you switch slides, the last slide will always be visible. "If" you've had flicker in the past, then I would argue that you're doing it wrong

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, I'll have to think about it more.